# Chain onto native Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, method-chaining

**tl;dr:**

How can I chain onto Javascript's map() with my own function? Like -

```
stuff.map(i => i.key).avg()
```

where avg() is my own function to compute the average of the array returned by map?

---

In moving away from objects and toward functional programming with pure functions, I've lost the handy

```
return this;
```

that allows me to chain.

If I have

```
let stuff = [
  {id: 1, name: 'tuan', country: 'VN', age: 23},
  {id: 2, name: 'nhung', country: 'US', age: 25},
  ...

//my own filter to pass as a param to native filter()
var filt = x => j => j.country === x;

//my own reducer for an array that computes an average
let avg = (arr) => (arr.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i) / arr.length);
```

then

```
stuff.filter(filt('VN')).map(i => i.age)
```

would return something like

```
[23, 34, 45]
```

but

```
stuff.filter(filt('VN')).map(i => i.age).avg()
```

gives an error like

```
filter().map().avg() is not a function
```

How can we write functions that chain onto the native ones?

Comment: Is `avg()` added to Array.prototype?

Comment: avg(stuff.filter(filt('VN')).map(i => i.age)) , try this

Comment: @suraj I get the vibe that people don't dig adding onto prototype these days because of collisions. Is that the way you would do it?

Comment: avg is your custom function, which is not added to the array prototype. It accepts a parameter and return avg, so pass the array as parameter you get from map and filter

Comment: the only way `map().avg()` would work were if array had `avg()` function..since map returns array

Comment: @Anmol Mittal Thanks - that certainly solves the problem at hand, but this is a simplified version of more complex filtering. Is the answer here that you can't chain this? I'd really like to write my filters in a readable way like stuff.removeThis().computeThat().computeAgain()

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map, you can see how map polyfill is implemented (scroll a bit down) and implement your function accordingly by changing logic, and you will be able to access your function by adding it to array prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method chaining isn't compatible with function composition. But instead of modifying built-in prototypes or fall back on subtyping, you can create a container type that allows you to compose pure functions in the context of method chaining:

```js
function Box(x) {
  return new.target ? (this.x = x, this) : new Box(x)
}

Box.prototype.fold = function fold(f) {return f(this.x)};
Box.prototype.map = function map(f) {return new Box(f(this.x))};
Box.prototype.toString = function toString() {return `Box(${this.x})`};

const id = x => x;

const stuff = [
  {id: 1, name: 'foo', country: 'VN', age: 23},
  {id: 2, name: 'bar', country: 'US', age: 25},
  {id: 2, name: 'bat', country: 'VN', age: 34},
  {id: 2, name: 'baz', country: 'VN', age: 45}
];

const filt = x => j => j.country === x;

const avg = (arr) => (arr.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i) / arr.length);

console.log(
  Box(stuff.filter(filt('VN')).map(i => i.age))
  .map(xs => avg(xs))
  .fold(id) // yields 34
);
```

`Box` is a functor and you can put values of any type into this container. With `map` you can apply functions to the value inside the functor and get a new functor with the transformed value back. `fold` behaves identically, except that it returns the bare value.

Maybe you have noticed that my example is a little verbose and I could have spared me the mapping.

Comment: functors - brilliant. this is exactly it. powerful stuff! really - thanks so much.

Comment: @Harold You're welcome. If you are interested in this stuff look into [prof Frisby's course](https://egghead.io/courses/professor-frisby-introduces-composable-functional-javascript) for composable, functional Javascript.

Comment: nice - that first video had a good example of this, and even addressed my concerns about performance. functional js is a stretch at first but it really is great after figuring out how to do it. this was one of those 'aha' moments.

Comment: @Harold the Professor Frisby learning materials are very nice – I have some [other Identity functor write-ups](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+identity+functor), in case you're interested

Comment: @ftor I see you experimenting with new writing styles again ^_^

Comment: @naomik Yeah, we won't get a composition operator ever. Function composition is dead in Javascript. Long live the method chain!

Comment: @naomik yes those answers are very interesting, especially your explanation of the Identity functor. great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

`avg(stuff.filter(filt('VN')).map(i => i.age))`

because you defined the `avg` function that expects `arr` as its argument. You did not extend the `Array` prototype with the `avg` method.

Answer (score 1):

create a avg method on the Array.prototype

```js
Array.prototype.avg = function() {
    return this.reduce((a,b) => Number(a) + Number(b)) / this.length;
}
var array = [
    { id: 1, key:2 },
    { id: 2, key:3 },
    { id: 3, key:7 },
    { id: 4, key:6 },
    { id: 5, key:4 }
]
var avg = array.map(i => i.key).avg();
console.log(avg);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention why this should *not* be done (although it works).

Comment: Yes, it should NOT be done by any rational person - though I'm not entirely convinced why myself. What's the difference between polyfilling a "new" method for "old" browser, and adding something you find useful :p

Comment: So is the answer that this is not possible without modifying the Array.prototype and that I just shouldn't attempt to chain in this way?

Comment: In polyfilling, you add a method with *standardised* name and behaviour that should already exist in the environment, while when adding something yourself you have no idea what it might collide with in the future. Of course it's a "know-what-im-doing" tradeoff, depending on the extent of possibly affected source, and the requirements for future maintainability :-D

Comment: @Harold - strictly, yes - with ES2015+ you could (possibly, I haven't tried) create a class that inherits from an Array, do your funky stuff there, but I'm not convinced that is entirely appropriate either

Comment: @Jaromanda Right on man. This code would be so much easier to read a year later if it were like first().then().next().after() instead of next(after(first().then())). But I guess I can't do that without modifying the Array. This was a good discussion for me anyway. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining isn't magic — you're just calling a method on the return value of a function. If the function doesn't support that method, you need to add it to the prototype.

This works because `map` returns and array and arrays have a `join()` method:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.map((i) => i *2 ).join(",")
```

But arrays don't have an `avg()` method unless you add it so the chaining won't work.

Comment: Thanks - this solves the average situation yes, but my example is a contrived, simplified version. I want to chain a readable set of filters like firstThis().thenThat().thenAnother().thenSomeMo().

Comment: Maybe the best way to do that is to write your own collection object that supports all the operations you want.

Comment: I hear you - actually I'm trying to rewrite some OO code into FP code. The OO code already has methods that handle this, so I'm trying to rewrite it with pure functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have some options here for sure. There's no single right way to achieve what you want. I think your best option is to extend JavaScript's Array class.

```
class PizzaCollection extends Array {
   // .. collection specific methods here...
   avg() {
     // you can iterate on `this`
   }
}
```

.map, .filter, etc will all return back an instance of PizzaCollection.

Try it out!

```
const j = new PizzaCollection(1, 2, 3)
const k = j.map((num) => num * num)
k instanceof PizzaCollection // returns true
k.avg() // returns the avg
```